# How many types of pieces or icons are in Dashpaad (10x10 board)?

Tags: history, chess-variants, chessboards

Dashpaad board (10x10 square blocks) have 100 squares in total. How the pieces fit in this board and what are their names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dashpaad board (10x10 square blocks) have following type of pieces:

1 इंद्र Indra (King)
1 मंत्री Mantri (Minister)
1 नारद राजऋषि Naarad or Raajrishi (Noble Man)
1 सेनापति Senapati (General which became Queen)
2 महारथी Maharathi (Rooks)
2 शूरवीर Shoorveer (Knights)
2 गज आरोही Gajarohi (Modern Bishop)
8 पद्ति Padati (Pawns)
4 चारक Chaarak (Impersonator or Spy)

[image: pieces on dashpaad]

- King and Minster falls under same Royal category.
- Noble godman falls
  under Immortal Category.
- General is the commandar of Army.
- Normal Officers.
- Common people.
- Impersonator can copy anyone step.

No piece can exceed its count. For an example, this means that there can be only 1 General and only 2 Bishops as total.

To understand the categories and all these pieces, explore  other related questions in this portal. Also, Kautilya Arthshastra book is a good read.

[image: Dashpada or Dashpaad (10x10 Board) on Kautilya Period]

Comment: Do you have a source/reference for these information?

Comment: These cloth and stone based boards are in museums now. The game is limited to few people. I learnt in 2005 and noted down all points. If you will got through the summary of Kautilya Arthshastra then you will learn the game. Learn 6 principles.. For references, Mahabharat has this game named as Dhyut. But last four Corners called naaglok have no clue to anyone till now.. Even some ancient samples are uncovering